# How to validate entry in tkinter?

Tags: python, function, validation, user-interface, tkinter

I have found some answers to this question but none of the answers have worked on my program.
I am trying to validate the name variable in my code but `isalpha()` is not a function used in `tkinter`.

Here is my code so far:

```
class newUser:
    root.title("Sign Up")
    header = Label(root, text = "Sign Up!\n")
    header.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E)

    global results
    results = False

    def getName(): #Getting name of the user
        global name

        nameX = Label(root, text = "Please enter your name: ")
        nameX.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

        name = Entry(root)
        name.grid(row =1, column = 1)
        #name = name.get()

        if name.isalpha() and name != "":
            name = name
            #newUser.getAge()
        else:
            print("Please ensure you have entered your name. Thank you. ")
            newUser.getName()
        root.mainloop()


newUser.getName()
```

I tried to use the `name.get()` but it created an endless loop.
Any ideas?

Comment: The indentation of the code for class `newUser` is messed up. Even if you fix it, you need to create and instance of the class before you call any of its methods (if that's what `getName()` is supposed to be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isalpha()` is a built-in function of `str` objects. Calling `isalpha()` on `name`, which was defined to be a `tkinter.Entry` object will raise an exception because `tkinter.Entry` has no such function. While you are correct in attempting to use the `get()` function, which is a function of `tkinter.Entry` objects and does return a `str` which supports `isalpha()` calls, your implementation is a bit off.

You are entering into a recursion because `name.get()` immediately returns a string which fails the conditional on the `name != ""` check causing the Python interpreter to fall into the catch-all `else` clause which calls `newUser.getName()`, the function we were already in, and the process repeats until you exceed Python's maximum recursion depth. You don't want to call `get()` on the `tkinter.Entry` object *immediately* because that gives the user no time to enter anything. Instead, `get()` should be called after some event has occurred, such as a submit button being pressed.

Instead, try something like the following:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class NewUser:

    def __init__(self):

        self.name = None

        root.title("Sign Up")

        self.headerLabel  = tk.Label (root, text = "Sign Up!\n")
        self.nameLabel    = tk.Label (root, text = "Please enter your name: ")
        self.nameField    = tk.Entry (root)
        self.submitButton = tk.Button(root, text = "Submit", command = self.saveName)

        self.headerLabel.grid (row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        self.nameLabel.grid   (row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "W")
        self.nameField.grid   (row = 1, column = 1)
        self.submitButton.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = "EW")

    def saveName(self):

        name = self.nameField.get()

        if name.isalpha() and name != "":

            self.name = name
            print("Name saved: {}".format(self.name))

        else:

            print("Please ensure you have entered your name. Thank you.")

user = NewUser()

root.mainloop()
```

This code will generate the following window:

[image: tkinter window without entry text]

At this point, if you hit the `Submit` button, `name` will be an empty string and will fail the `name != ""` comparison. Consequently, the following is printed to the console:

```
Please ensure you have entered your name. Thank you.
```

However, if you enter your name, assuming you only include alpha characters like so:

[image: tkinter window with entry text]

The following is printed to the console upon pressing `Submit`:

```
Name saved: Erick
```

And the saved name is now accessible via the `self.name` member variable of our `NewUser` class.